# How can u bulid a tree with weighted egdes

Tags: python, list, binary-tree

I am trying to construct a A weighted General tree.

Are there any built-in data structures in Python to implement it? Or any simplified code ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

A tree is a special graph. Therefore you might want to have a look at some graph libraries, e.g. [networkx](https://networkx.org/).